# How to prevent clicking a button from making other elements become blur?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Let's say there is a textarea and a button. 

After clicking the button, the textarea will become blur, but I don't want this. 

I want clicking the button to NOT make the textarea blur.

Could anyone teach me how to do this?
<>
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just cancel the mousedown event on the button

```
<div v-on:mousedown="handler">Button</div>
```

handler:

```
methods: {handler(event) {event.preventDefault(); event.stopPropagation()}}
```

As the button will not gain focus on click, the textarea will not be blurred.
Another sideeffect of cancelling mousedown is that the click event is still available.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the button click and focus on the textarea:

```
<textarea id="text-area" />
<button onClick="buttonClicked()" > Click Me </button>

<script>

    function buttonClicked() {
       document.getElementById("text-area").focus();
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Sorry this doesn't work, because the button will still make the textarea blur, then makes it focus again. In my implementation, I need the button to NOT make the textarea blur at all. Thank you all the same!

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure set attribute of button Type to "button"